# Xcode 6 Architecture

Tags: ios, xcode

When build the app in *Xcode 6* with having valid architectures as *arm7 arm7s* working fine.And when I changed the valid Architecture to *arm64 arm7 amr7s*, it is throwing error like 'ARC semantic issue'.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What code throws an error? What is the exact error message?

Comment: "_OBJC_CLASS_$_XMLToDictionary", referenced from: This issue occuring when build with xcode 6 and keeping valid acrhitecure as arm64 armv7 armv7s

Comment: Is the class XMLToDictionary part of some library?  Perhaps one that wasn't doesn't include 64-bit?